# Convert groovy.util.Node to org.dom.w3c.Node

Tags: dom, groovy

I am trying to convert groovy.util.Node returned by groovy.util.XMLParser to org.dom.w3c.Node. The way I am currently doing that is via serializing it into a String.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document bookedItemDoc = factory
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bookedItemXmlString.getBytes()));
Element bookedItemElement = bookedItemDoc.getDocumentElement();
domNode.setAny(bookedItemElement);
```

Is there a simpler and better way to do this?

Comment: What's the problem with the way You're converting it?

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with the node, you could write an adapter class that would wrap the groovy Node and implement the DOM Node methods you care about.

Comment: @Opal The problem with serializing and re-parsing it is that each of such operations take about 37ms.

Comment: @bdkosher Unfortunately, I need the a org.w3c.Element object to set an Object field. Unfortunately, this Object was genereated using JAXB bindings and the Element field came from mapping an xs:any XSD node.